# $C^1$ function orthogonality implies maximum

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis

I'm trying to figure out this problem that I found in a Ph.d. entry test. It's probably taken out of Lima's analysis books. So far I have nothing so any hints would be great.

---

Let $F: \mathbb{R}^n \setminus 0 \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $C^1$ function such that $\nabla f(x)$ and $x$ are orthogonal for all $x.$

Prove that $F$ attains its maximum.

Comment: On Math StackExchange, people who don't supply context of some sort usually get down voted (and their question closed.)  You must have some ideas about why the assertion is true...?

Comment: I did supply all the context I had at the time, I hope users on Math StackExchange usually read the question before down voting.

Comment: Everyone has their own notion as to how much context should be included.  They get real touchy if they think someone is just using the list as a homework-doing site.  You'd benefit in the future by making your posts not look like you just posted a homework question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the function $g(t)=f(tx)$. Compute its derivative.

$tg'(t)=\nabla f(tx)\cdot tx=0$.

Therefore $g$ is constant. That means that $f$ is constant on each ray.

This means that the values that $f$ takes are exactly those that it takes on the unit circle, which is compact.

Comment: For some reason I can't upvote yet, but thank you so much for your help!.

Comment: @AlejandroSantacruz No problem.

Comment: @AlejandroSantacruz There is a 7-10 min interval between when a question is asked and when an answer can be accepted.